# React webpack - Setting up a script to build a project

Tags: reactjs, webpack

If I enter npm run start, project is launched. If the input npm run build exists, it throws Unexpected token import exception on imports, webpack.

How can i properly assemble a project?

Everything is gathered in one folder. If i run index.html it will work okay.

My package.js :

```
{
  "name": "your-pizza",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Order pizza Omsk",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch",
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.dev.js",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/runServer.js",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* src tools",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch"
  },
  ...
}
```

My webpack :

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

export default {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    noInfo: false,
    entry: [
        'eventsource-polyfill',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')
    ],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
            {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]},
            {test: /bootstrap.+\.(jsx|js)$/, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window'},
            {test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-loader'}
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: You should always ask questions in english on this site.

Comment: Questions in English is more likely to be addressed.

Comment: I edited question to english.
@ks_on_v I dont know JS well but index.html would always work due to fact that its html.

Comment: @Samed: you forgot the title. But in future, please don't translate posts for someone; we don't know if the OP knows English well enough to follow feedback and assess answers.  It is better to close such posts as *unclear* instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters he can always try google translate to understand it:D After all, he seeks answers no matter what

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu: that's not the point. We seek *quality, on-topic questions*; it doesn't matter that the OP wants answers if their question is too low quality or off-topic. Most question require the OP to be reasonably versed in English to keep things on track. And Google Translate is not nearly good enough; I invite you to try to follow a question (with comments and answers) on https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ via Google Translate, see if you can follow all the subtleties.